# Setting up CRS for Mars images taken by a satellite

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, mars

I have a PDS image of the Valles Marineris taken by the Mars Orbiter Missions (MOM) Mars Colour Camera (MCC). I have to generate a depth map and I am in the process of creating a 3D model.
In the provided metadata I have latitude and longitudes of 9 reticle points on the given image.
When I try to set the provided CRS I am prompted with the following error:

> No transform is available between EPSG:4326 - WGS 84 and Unknown CRS: GEOGCRS["unknown",DATUM["unknown",ELLIPSOID["unkno….
> proj_create_operations: Source and target ellipsoid do not belong to the same >celestial body

The CRS that I tried were the following:

- Mars_2000_(Sphere) ESRI:104971
- GCS_Mars_1979 ESRI:104904.

Are there any suggestions for setting up a CRS or any other way to generate a depth map?

Comment: The "No transform is available between EPSG:4326 - WGS 84 and Unknown CRS" seem to imply that some of your data are recognized as having a CRS from earth, could you provide more information on what you did and how you did it ?

Comment: i just added the raster layer in qgis while setting up the CRS i chose the mars one but it gave me the mestioned error

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using a non Earth projection for the layer, must check on the No projection (or unknown/non-Earth) option for the project map, in Project Properties, CRS tab.

And do not change the unknown CRS of the layer.

Comment: 0

But a problem with this solution is that (afaik) you cannot create vector layers setting CRS to no projection, and drawing polygons for known or interesting sites becomes a problem. If the area is small, perhaps setting a user CRS for a simple cartesian projection could be better. This would be good for mapping relatively small field plots on Earth as well

Comment: The layer CRS is OK, and other layers in the project must have the same CRS. The problem is with the projection of the map. At least unitl QGIS 3.18 the on-the-fly reprojection to the map uses always EPSG:4326 as pivot, which is Earth-based, therefore the error in the transformation from the layer about not being the same celestial body as the map.