# Pixel size convert from degrees to meters of Martian DEM

Tags: coordinate-system, qgis-3, dem, pixel, mars

I have a Martian DEM whose pixel size is specified in degrees instead of meters. I was trying to convert in Global Mapper but it didn't work. Now I am trying convert in QGIS with projections but it always write a system error that say "No transform available between ESTI:104971 and Custom CRS". By the way The same happens the most Martian projections. I was trying to add a New Projection but if I changed WKT to proj string or proj string to WKT, the geodetic date and any important data disappeared. How can I convert the pixel size from degrees to meter in QGIS or any other software?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour], which emphasizes the importance of asking One question per Question. Please choose which topic you want to address and [Edit] the Question accordingly.. It's quite likely that the data is *signed*, so the large values are actually ones- or twos-complement negative values.

Comment: See for the QGIS error message https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/368706/setting-up-crs-for-mars-images-taken-by-a-satellite

Answer (score 0):

On Earth a minute of arc (1/60 of a degree) North-South is one nautical mile or 1852 m. Mars is 0.531 times the size of Earth, so a minute of arc NS on Mars is 983.4 m, an arcsecond NS on Mars is 16.4 meters, a degree NS on Mars is 59 km.

The equatorial radius of Mars is slightly larger than the polar radius, so for East-West you have to multiply with the equatorial-polar ratio 3396.2/3376.2

Furthermore: length of an East-West degree diminishes with lattitude and is zero at the poles, so you have to multiply with cos(lattitude).

marsfacts https://nssdc.gsfc.nasa.gov/planetary/factsheet/marsfact.html

Comment: The ESRI:104971 CRS (Not ESTI as in the Q) has a radius of 3396190m [https://epsg.io/104971] which you can use to create results to a few more decimal points if needed (one Martian degree = 59.2747km, one Martian arc-second = 16.47m etc).