# How can I change the pixel-size from degrees to meters?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, dem, pixel, mars

I have a Martian DEM whose pixel size is specified in degrees instead of meters. I was trying to convert in Global Mapper but it didn't work. Now I am trying convert in QGIS with projections but it always write a system error that say "No transform available between ESRI:104971 and Custom CRS". By the way the same happens the most Martian projections. I was trying to add a New Projection but if I changed WKT to proj string or proj string to WKT, the geodetic date and any important data disappeared.

How can I convert the pixel size from degrees to meter in QGIS or any other software?

Comment: possibly related ~https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/368706/setting-up-crs-for-mars-images-taken-by-a-satellite

Comment: One way to really irk folks on this forum is to post a duplicate of a question that has been closed! You can edit your previous question to provide additional clarity and code or workflow.